# subprocess.check_output fails with CalledProcessError but error is empty string. Command works in terminal

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, ffprobe

I want to run the command `ffprobe -i test.m4a -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"`. It works in the terminal and returns output code 0, but running it with subprocess, i.e.

```
subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-i', 'test.m4a', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv="p=0"'])
```

raises a `CalledProcessError` - `{Command} returned non-zero exit status 1.`. I tried running this command in a try-except loop and printing the error details, but it just outputs as an empty byte string `b''`.

Comment: Look at `stderr` to identify the error, as written in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Answer (score 1):

One way for debugging the issue is adding `-report` argument:

```
subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-i', 'output.mp4', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv="p=0"', '-report'])
```

`-report` is used for creating a log file with name like `ffprobe-20220811-232043.log`.

The log files shows the following error:
`[csv @ 00000213297fe640] Failed to set option '"p' with value '0"' provided to writer context`

The log files shows that the executed "shell command" is:
`ffprobe -i output.mp4 -show_entries "format=duration" -v quiet -of "csv=\"p=0\"" -report`

The solution is removing the quotes from `"p=0"`:

```
subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-i', 'output.mp4', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv=p=0'])
```

Comment: I tried the `-report` thing in [this here question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/468485/python-subprocess-run-fails-with-calledprocesserror-on-mac-but-works-on-windows) but it didn't generate any `.log` file. Can you please specify in your post where this file is supposed to get generated? It looks like it's also the quotes in my case but I need the quotes because the path may have directory names with spaces in them.

Comment: looks like the solution to my problem is https://stackoverflow.com/a/74225674/21109385 where I have to transform the command to string using `" ".join(command)`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the subprocess.run instead of check_output.

```
subprocess.run(command, stdout=output, encoding="utf-8")
```

Command = is the variable that houses the command you want , no need for separation using the commas.

stdout = Output = means that the output should be recorded in the file called (Output) which you can create beforehand.

encoding = just means to make sure it's encoded into texts from bytes